# How to Skip do loop iteration if specific criteria is met

Tags: excel, vba

I apologize if my question is vague. I have a code that is calculating the costs of a bus trip based on the number of people in the party. The code first has to decide If the party is under 20 or over 120. If that criteria is met I want to return a message box saying that the party is to small or to large to accommodate and then set the prices and inputs to 0 on my spreadsheet. The exit do will not work because it ends the loop completely. Also I don't want to exit sub because I need to check for multiple lines of data and calculate the costs. If I don't put any sort of exit it will set those values to 0 but will continue to the calculation process and end up leaving the wrong values so I need it to skip to the end of the loop and then run the loop again.

Thanks!

```
Dim N As String 'N = Name
Dim D As Date 'D = Date
Dim P As Integer 'P = Number of people
Dim H As Single 'H = Number of hours
Dim NS As Integer 'NS = Number of Small Buses
Dim NL As Integer 'NL = Number of Large Buses
Dim BP As Currency 'BP = Base Price
Dim OH As Single 'OH = Overtime Hours
Dim OC As Currency 'OC = Overtime Charge
Dim TP As Currency 'TP = Total Price
Dim PPBR As Currency 'PPBR = Per-person Base Rate
Dim EHP As Single 'EHP = Extra Hourly Percent
Dim myRow As Integer 'helping to paste output
Dim oRow As Integer '

Do Until IsEmpty(Cells(oRow, 1))

P = Cells(oRow, 3)
H = Cells(oRow, 4)
NS = 0
NL = 0

'Checking that there is enough people to continue
If P < 20 Then

MsgBox "The Minimum # of persons is 20", , "Sorry!"


    NS = 0
    NL = 0
    BP = 0
    OH = 0
    OC = 0
    TP = 0

    Cells(oRow, 7) = NS
    Cells(oRow, 8) = NL
    Cells(oRow, 9) = BP
    Cells(oRow, 10) = OH
    Cells(oRow, 11) = OC
    Cells(oRow, 12) = TP

    Exit Do
    
 ElseIf P > 120 Then
  
    'checking that there are not to many participants.

    MsgBox "Sorry the maximum amount of Persons is 120!", , "Sorry!"
    
    NS = 0
    NL = 0
    BP = 0
    OH = 0
    OC = 0
    TP = 0

    Cells(oRow, 7) = NS
    Cells(oRow, 8) = NL
    Cells(oRow, 9) = BP
    Cells(oRow, 10) = OH
    Cells(oRow, 11) = OC
    Cells(oRow, 12) = TP
    
    Exit Do
    

    'solving how many busses will be needed based on the amount of people
    ElseIf P >= 20 And P <= 25 Then
        NS = 1
            
        ElseIf P >= 26 And P <= 50 Then
            NS = 2
            ElseIf P >= 51 And P <= 60 Then
                NL = 1
                
                ElseIf P >= 61 And P <= 85 Then
                    NS = 1
                    NL = 1
                    
                    ElseIf P >= 86 And P <= 120 Then
                        NL = 2
                        

End If
'calculate base price
BP = P * PPBR
'Calculating with no overtime
If H < 5 Then

    TP = BP
    OC = 0
    OH = 0
    Cells(oRow, 7) = NS
    Cells(oRow, 8) = NL
    Cells(oRow, 9) = BP
    Cells(oRow, 10) = OH
    Cells(oRow, 11) = OC
    Cells(oRow, 12) = TP

'calculating overtime over 9 hours (which will only be 4 hours)
ElseIf H > 9 Then
    
    
    OH = 4
    OC = BP * OH * EHP
    TP = OC + BP
    Cells(oRow, 7) = NS
    Cells(oRow, 8) = NL
    Cells(oRow, 9) = BP
    Cells(oRow, 10) = OH
    Cells(oRow, 11) = OC
    Cells(oRow, 12) = TP
        
        'calculating overtime between 0 and 4 hours
        Else
        OH = H - 5
        OC = BP * OH * EHP
        TP = OC + BP
        Cells(oRow, 7) = NS
        Cells(oRow, 8) = NL
        Cells(oRow, 9) = BP
        Cells(oRow, 10) = OH
        Cells(oRow, 11) = OC
        Cells(oRow, 12) = TP
        

End If

oRow = oRow + 1
NS = 0
NL = 0
BP = 0
OH = 0
OC = 0
TP = 0


Loop



End Sub
```

Comment: You can look into the keyword Continue, or structure your code in a way that you don't execute calculation if you don't meet certain criteria.

Comment: @David.C - you may be thinking of VB.Net. VBA doesn't have `Continue`.

Comment: @BigBen  I just assumed VBA had the Continue keyword. Thanks for correcting me.

Comment: Eh... yeah it's kind of unfortunate that it doesn't :-( I agree with the structure comment though.

Answer (score 0):

The typical solution for this type of issue in VBA is to restructure your code so that the calculation part is in a separate function to the part that iterates over the cells.  You can then safely exit the calculation function if the correct criteria are not met without affecting the iteration.